when OpenTelemetry Collector eventhubReceiver stoage="file_storage", collector pod cannot startup with permission error

I want to use OpenTel Connector Receiver=azureeventhubreceiver to collect data in Azure eventhub , and configuration as below

reference:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/azureeventhubreceiver
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/extension/storage/filestorage/testdata/config.yaml
receiver

azureeventhub:
  connection: "${EVENTHUB_ENDPOINT}"
  offset: "latest"
  storage: "file_storage"
  format: "azure"   


extensions:

file_storage:
  directory: .
file_storage/all_settings:
  directory: .
  compaction:
    directory: .
    on_start: true
    on_rebound: true
    rebound_trigger_threshold_mib: 16
    rebound_needed_threshold_mib: 128
    max_transaction_size: 2048
    cleanup_on_start: true
  timeout: 1s
  fsync: true



but pod cannot startup ,  error info: permission denied.

{"level":"debug","ts":1724433105.4518387,"caller":"azureeventhubreceiver@v0.101.0/eventhubhandler.go:58","msg":"Error connecting to Storage","kind":"receiver","name":"azureeventhub","data_type":"logs","error":"open receiver_azureeventhub_: permission denied"}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.451868,"caller":"zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:176","msg":"[core] [Server #3 ListenSocket #4]ListenSocket created","grpc_log":true}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.451877,"caller":"service@v0.101.0/service.go:232","msg":"Starting shutdown..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.451891,"caller":"healthcheck/handler.go:132","msg":"Health Check state change","kind":"extension","name":"health_check","status":"unavailable"}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.4520166,"caller":"zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:176","msg":"[core] [Server #1 ListenSocket #2]ListenSocket deleted","grpc_log":true}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.4521346,"caller":"zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:176","msg":"[core] [Server #3 ListenSocket #4]ListenSocket deleted","grpc_log":true}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.4524822,"caller":"extensions/extensions.go:59","msg":"Stopping extensions..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.4525328,"caller":"zpagesextension@v0.101.0/zpagesextension.go:98","msg":"Unregistered zPages span processor on tracer provider","kind":"extension","name":"zpages"}
{"level":"info","ts":1724433105.4525828,"caller":"service@v0.101.0/service.go:246","msg":"Shutdown complete."}
Error: cannot start pipelines: open receiver_azureeventhub_: permission denied
2024/08/23 17:11:45 collector server run finished with error: cannot start pipelines: open receiver_azureeventhub_: permission denied

I am not sure why , Hope someone can help me .

I want to know how to solve this problem

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/13630
One issue worth noting is that the official otel collector docker container is built using FROM scratch, which means that there's not a writable directory by default
After I build docker images using FROM alpine, it is solved.
